# Selecting multiple tags with the same className?

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, web-crawler, x-ray

Using this syntax:

```
x('http://www.viadeo.com/fr/company/unicef', 
    '.page-content',
    [{
    img:'img@src',
    bio:'.pan-desc-description',

    org:'.pan-desc-footer-element @element-value',
    link: '.element-value a@href',
    **twitter:'.element-value a@href'** // I get the previous link not the twitter one 

}]).write('result.json')
```

There are multiple items within the website with that specific classname, but it only returns the first one. Is there a way to grab all of them and maybe I can do a .limit with that return? I apologize if it's in the documentation, I've read through it twice and it looks like it's not explicitly said anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take advantage of the chrome inspector tool to get proper selector,

Here, this code worked for me,

```
var Xray = require('x-ray');
var x = Xray();
x('http://www.viadeo.com/fr/company/unicef', 
'.page-content',
 [{
  img:'img@src',
  bio:'.pan-desc-description',
  org:'.pan-desc-footer-element @element-value',
  link: '.element-value a@href',
  twitter:'.mbs:nth-child(4) a@href' // or use div.element-value.gu.gu-last a@href
}]).write('result.json')
```

And there, we get this result.

```
[
  {
    "img": "http://static8.viadeo-static.com/fzv6VNzGukb7mt5oV0Nl-wQxCDI=/fit-in/200x200/filters:fill(white)/7766b960b98f4e85affdab7ffa9863c7/1434471183.jpeg",
    "bio": "Le Fonds des Nations unies pour l'enfance (abrégé en UNICEF ou Unicef pour United Nations International Children's Emergency Fund en anglais) est une agence de l'ONU consacrée à l'amélioration et à la promotion de la condition des enfants. Son nom était originellement United Nations International Children's Emergency Fund, dont elle a conservé l'acronyme. Elle a activement participé à la rédaction, la conception et la promotion de la convention relative aux droits de l'enfant (CIDE), adoptée suite au sommet de New York en 1989. Son revenu total en 2006 a été de 2 781 millions Dollar US.\r\n          L'UNICEF a reçu le prix Nobel de la paix en 1965.",
    "link": "http://www.unicef.org/",
    "twitter": "http://www.twitter.com/UNICEF "
  }
]
```

Here is how you can get a proper selector on chrome:

First you right click and click inspect.
[image]

Then you click copy selector, and use it.
[image]

When you copy the selector, it'll say something like,

```
#pan-desc > div.pan-desc-grey > div > div:nth-child(4) > div.element-value.gu.gu-last > a
```

You can use it directly, or refine it.

Comment: Thank you from the deep of my heart, now i understand better how it work !

Answer (score 1):

You just have to wrap what you want "split" with brackets.

Here is code that worked for me.

```
var Xray = require('x-ray');
var x = Xray();

x('http://www.viadeo.com/fr/company/unicef',
    '.page-content',
    {
    img:'img@src',
    bio:'.pan-desc-description',

    org:'.pan-desc-footer-element @element-value',
    link: ['.element-value a@href'],
    //twitter:'.element-value a@href'

})
(function(err, title) {
  console.log(title)
});
```

I also removed the outer bracket as page content will never have more than one element so you would never want more than one.